# Iterative async scope

Tags: c#, concurrency, async-await

In the following code block:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> arr00 = new List<int>() {100, 0, 3, 8, 21};
            int index = 0;
            int tasks = 0;
            foreach (int num in arr00)
            {
                var innerIndex = index;
                Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{index}, {innerIndex}: {num}");
                    tasks++;
                });

                index++;
            }

            while (tasks < index) { }
        }
```

The output is

`5, 1: 0
5, 4: 21
5, 2: 3
5, 3: 8
5, 0: 100`

How did the async task keep the correct count for innerIndex, but not the hoisted index?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this: [Captured variable in a loop in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/captured-variable-in-a-loop-in-c-sharp).

Answer (score 0):

The `foreach` loop starts a `task` completes iteration starts another `task` in next iteration and so on. The `fareach` completes all iteration and sets value of `index` as `5` even before 1st task starts. That's why you find value of `index` as `5` for all tasks. 
Now if you add a `Wait` each task to complete then value of `index` and `innerIndex` will match. But you will loos the advantage of executing those task in parallel.

Change the code as:

```
foreach (int num in arr00)
{
    var innerIndex = index;
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{index}, {innerIndex}: {num}");
        tasks++;
    }).Wait();  //Wait for task to complete

    index++;
}
```

Output:

```
0, 0: 100
1, 1: 0
2, 2: 3
3, 3: 8
4, 4: 21
```